# Add encryption to JDBCLoginService in Jetty

Tags: java, encryption, jetty, forms-authentication

I've configured servlet, and other things needed to have role-based access to resources. I'm using JDBCLoginService to access roles data from DB. All works great, my only problem is: how to configure Jetty that in database I'll have passwords encrypted (preferably not MD5).
I found several docs saying you can run some tool given by jetty and it produces you MD5 or OBF, etc. But I wonder how to get list of avail ciphers? 
I believe in table with users, column with password should have something like "MD5:897897979".

But I want to add users to this table by functionality like register/signup. So I need to encrypt password sent from browser and put to DB. But I can't control algorithm which is used by JDBCLoginService to check data sent by user from login page.

I believe it's implemented in some smart way that not much extra code is needed, but I can't just find info how to do it :/

Comment: That seems awfully custom.  Also, the actual passwords should never be stored in the database, even encrypted.  They should instead be hashed (with salt) and compared with the database hash.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21646234/775715

Comment: This is exactly what I want to achieve. To put into DB hash of password, using some common hash techniques. I wondering if there is any way to do it automagicaly without writing own classes to do so, rather to configure/bind some components.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and tried to resort to the facilities provided by the [Password](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security-secure-passwords.html) class in the Jetty distribution.

However, eventually I couldn't adopt that approach since I was in need of storing the passwords hashed with a specific algorithm (namely sha256 or sha512) and I couldn't find a way to get the JDBCLoginService work with such hash algorithms.

This was kind of a let down, especially because Tomcat comes with the support of those algorithms out of the box when it comes to handle database-backed authentication scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem today. And the solution I ended doing is to have the sha256 calculated for the password input field in the browser side. You can do it on form submit or any other event if you are careful not to re-hash. Simple check or password length less that 64 would be sufficient to avoid rehash.  I used the below to do the hash

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest

Paradoxically this solution makes it stronger as the password is hashed from the browser itself. Of course it could be exploited from this same web app but not in others that do not use hashing from browser if the is is used for other authentications.